# Arraylist vs List vs Dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can anyone save me?  I have the following code:

```
private List<string> GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
{
    List <string> uniques = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < docs.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] tokens = docs[i].Split(' ');

        List<string> toktolist = new List<string>(tokens.ToList());

        var query = toktolist.GroupBy(word => word)
             .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
             .Select(g => g.Key)
             .Take(20000);              

        foreach (string k in query)
        {
            if (!uniques.Contains(k)) 
                uniques.Add(k);
        }
    }            

    return uniques;            
}
```

It is about generate terms from number of documents based on the highest frequency. i did the same procedure using dictionary. in both cases spent 440 milliseconds. but the surprise was when i used the procedure with array list as in the following code

```
private ArrayList GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> yy = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    ArrayList uniques = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < docs.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] tokens = docs[i].Split(' ');
        yy.Clear();
        for (int j = 0; j < tokens.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!yy.ContainsKey(tokens[j].ToString()))
                    yy.Add(tokens[j].ToString(), 1);
                else
                    yy[tokens[j].ToString()]++;
            }

            var sortedDict = (from entry in yy
                              orderby entry.Value descending
                              select entry).Take(20000).ToDictionary
                          (pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);               

            foreach (string k in sortedDict.Keys)
            {                    
                if (!uniques.Contains(k)) 
                uniques.Add(k);
            }
        }            

        return uniques;            
    }
```

it spent 350 milliseconds. shouldn't Array list be slower than List and dictionary ?? please save me with this tense.

Comment: I don't know how you're measuring the time, but it looks like a very flawed performance test to me.  I don't see that you're "warming up" the VM, etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of this line? `List<string> toktolist = new List<string>(tokens.ToList());`. 1) It converts to a list *twice*. 2) You don't even need to convert to a list - the next line will work fine with an array.

Comment: Not much point in fretting over inefficient code.  *uniques* should of course be a HashSet<>

Comment: when u have text files in Unicode forms, you will see what is the suffering

Comment: Mark, that line to copy the array to list !!

Comment: I think you should be able to express this in a single linq statement.

Comment: @Mark, i want to return a List

Comment: @Magnus, I would appreciate your help

Comment: @Qaesar: Then you can use `return something.ToList();`. Just because you want to return a list doesn't mean that you're required to use lists for all your internal data structures.

Comment: @Mark, can you explain more ??

Comment: @Mark, the returned list must no duplicate items

Comment: @Qaesar: Discussing this in the comments is inefficient. See my answer.

Comment: Simply don't ever use `ArrayList`. That's an old, .NET 1.0 data structure that has been superceded by `List<T>`.

Comment: @Qaesar Mark is right. Also, converting the array to a list (with `.ToList()`) is unnecessary... you can just pass the array to the constructor (`List<string> toktolist = new List<string>(tokens);`) since an array is an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: If `docs = new[] { "a b b", "a a a" };` then your output is `{ "b", "a" }` even though `"a"` is more common than `"b"` in all docs. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does a lot of unnecessary work and uses inefficient data structures.

Try this instead:

```
private List<string> GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
{
     var result = docs
         .SelectMany(doc => doc.Split(' ')
                               .GroupBy(word => word)
                               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                               .Select(g => g.Key)
                               .Take(20000))
         .Distinct()
         .ToList();   
     return result;
}
```

Refactored version to make it easier to read:

```
private List<string> GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
{
    return docs.SelectMany(doc => ProcessDocument(doc)).Distinct().ToList();
}

private IEnumerable<string> ProcessDocument(string doc)
{
    return doc.Split(' ')
              .GroupBy(word => word)
              .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
              .Select(g => g.Key)
              .Take(10000);
}
```

Comment: aren't you missing a `)` after split?

Comment: @Qaesar: Errr.. did you actually try my code? It processes all the  terms of all documents and then puts the results in one list.

Comment: @mikez: No. The closing parenthesis for SelectMany appears a few lines down. I admit that the code could  be made clearer by splitting this method into two separate methods. I've tested the code, so I know it doesn't contain any compile errors.

Comment: @Qaesar: No, you're not right. Just stop talking and try the code. Then make your comments afterwards.

Comment: @MarkByers Yes, your code compiles but what I meant was that you are grouping for each word in each doc rather than for all the words in all the docs. The order is not correct unless you move that closing parenthesis.

Comment: @mikez: I'm just doing the same thing as the OP's code does. If you think the OPs code is wrong, I suggest you discuss it with him, not me. I can't comment on it as I don't know what he's trying to do.

Comment: @MarkByers you're totally right. it seems like a bizarre thing to want, but that's up to the OP.

Comment: @Qaesar: OP = Original Poster = You, Qaesar.

Answer (score 1):

I like Mark's solution.  However, I thought that if you leverage a Dictionary properly you could squeeze out some more performance.  Sure enough, this is a lot faster...

```
private static List<string> GenerateTerms(string[] docs)
{
    var termsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (var doc in docs)
    {
        var terms = doc.Split(' ');
        int uniqueTermsCount = 0;

        foreach (string term in terms)
        {
            if (termsDictionary.ContainsKey(term))
                termsDictionary[term]++;
            else
            {
                uniqueTermsCount++;
                termsDictionary[term] = 1;
            }
        }

        if (uniqueTermsCount >= 20000)
            break;
    }

    return (from entry in termsDictionary
                    orderby entry.Value descending
                    select entry.Key).ToList();
}
```

To explain briefly, `termsDictionary` holds a Dictionary of terms and the number of times each term is repeated.  Then the Linq query at the end returns the terms in descending order by the number of occurrences.

**UPDATE**

I added code to limit the unique number of terms to 20,000 per doc.

Here are the benchmarking results...

- 322 ms (Original)
- 284 ms (Mark Byers solution)
- 113 ms (Leveraging the Dictionary as above)

Below is the code I used to generate the `docs` array and run the tests...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] docs = new string[50000];

    for (int i = 0; i < docs.Length; i++)
    {
        docs[i] = "a man a plan a canal panama";
    }

    // warm up (don't time this)
    GenerateTermsOriginal(docs);

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Restart();
    var t1 = GenerateTermsOriginal(docs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

    sw.Restart();
    var t2 = GenerateTermsLinq(docs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

    sw.Restart();
    var t3 = GenerateTermsDictionary(docs);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
}
```

Comment: +1 for posting some figures. However your code doesn't quite do the same thing as the original code, so it's not a fair comparison - see mikez's comments for the difference. Also, could you post the code you used to benchmark (or at least the code you used to generate the test documents)? The specific test cases may have an impact on which solution is best (though I don't doubt my answer could be improved).

Comment: @Mark - I posted the code I used for the tests.  I'm not sure yet how the results would be different from the original.  I'll look everything over again...

Comment: @Steve,the returned List must have no duplicate items

Comment: @Qaesar - This won't return any duplicate items.  The use of the `Dictionary` ensures that.

Comment: @Steve, just to inform you. i tested your code , then i found the returned list contained number of terms much than the Original code and Mark code. so, could u tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: @Qaesar - Oh... I think I know why.  You're dealing with much larger texts, so the `Take(20000)` call is affecting the results.  In your code, the `Take(20000)` call is being made BEFORE the distinct operation is performed.  And in mine, it's after.

Comment: @Qaesar - If you wanted to, you could add a line inside the foreach like this `if (termsDictionary.Count >= 20000) break;` which should solve it.

Comment: @SteveWortham: That change still wouldn't make your code equivalent to the original.

Comment: @Mark, i think it is hard to conduct this task with dictionary as Steve suggested. right ?

Comment: @Qaesar - Alright, I looked at it again and noticed that you're actually limiting the number of terms to 20,000 per doc.  Is that what you meant?  It's an easy enough change.  See my update above.

Comment: `termsDictionary` can't have duplicate items.  It's physically impossible, as the Dictionary in .NET doesn't allow it.  But I realized that even with my latest change this still isn't giving you the right result because you need to order by the most common terms first, then only take the top 20,000.  Sigh... I know this is close, but I'm going to call it quits.